# What do you think about a physical Stack Overflow magazine?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blog

I definitely like reading the Stack Overflow's blog, but sometimes I just don't want to be sitting in front of my computer or reading through my smartphone specially when COVID-19 made us (at least me) a bit (a lot actually) more inclined to watch those screens all day long even after work.

I think that a monthly issued magazine would be awesome so that I (us) can relax on my couch and read about things I (we) like. Let me know you think. Nice day y'all.

Comment: There are already [online digest "newsletters"](https://stackexchange.com/digests) and [online SO blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/). Curious what content may "magazine" add to. Also, is this about physical magazines?

Comment: the magazine would be the articles from the blog among other things. Yes it would be a physical one.

Comment: Physical... I don't think there's any benefit for the company to publish a physical magazine, moreover the trouble with managing worldwide delivery...

Comment: I would be in favor of this. It would be much easier to ignore the exceptionally low-quality content posted on the blog if it were sent to me as a physical magazine, rather than crammed into my sidebar, which already serves many other useful purposes.

Comment: @AndrewT. you may have a point on the financial and logistical side of things but it could be a good way to spread the word even more about SO,  specially when there are topics that are not related to tech (and again, this would be as an option, people would still be able to go on the digest or the blog). But I guess, it's up to them weigh up the pros and cons.

Comment: @NeimadTL "*it could be a good way to spread the word even more about SO*" I posit that if somebody doesn't know of SO *yet*, I don't think a physical magazine would make it more known to them. Typically you find about SO when you search online for programming problems. If you haven't found any so far, it seems like a paper magazine would hardly entice you to start searching online.

Comment: Physical print is dead. Waste of money. Would rather see actual community issues be solved by hiring a developer than see money wasted on a magazine that nobody wants.

Comment: Really don't need to spread this low quality content to other formats

Comment: Soft, strong and thoroughly absorbent.  A picture of a puppy on the cover would also please:)

Comment: @CodyGray Kevin B, what do u mean by _low-quality content_ ? VLAZ, u can be a student (studying software or not, in regular school or self-taught) or a random person, walking in a kiosk and find out about it. I don't walk in kiosks that often anymore because I know what I like but sometimes I do (tho it's rare). For an interested newcomer or somebody who doesn't know what he/she wants yet, a magazine could or not spark the interest (for me it did back in the days). Still believe that for reading/learning stuff, paper is better (I'm dev sitting all day in front of computer, so might be bias).

Answer (score 9):

That's nice and all, but how are we going to comment on the articles? How would we click any links in the articles?

I don't see the benefit of using dead tree format over digital media.

A simple alternative would be to get a simple tablet, and read the blog on there. The added advantage is that the tablet allows you to access an infinite number of blogs.

Comment: I have nothing against digital media. I'm just saying a magazine could be an option. Shutting down the blog or the newsletter are absolutely not in my mind so that people can still go in there and click on different links. About the tablet, I wanted to avoid screens at all.

Comment: @NeimadTL Well... then pick something that already exists? Why must it be Stack Overflow that provides it? Just like Stack Overflow is not a replacement for the web, it is also not going to be a surrogate for existing printed media. Get books, get existing magazines. When it comes to books you don't want to look at screens but I can still recommend an eReader. It might not be paper but it definitely feels like you're reading from paper. It doesn't radiate like a computer screen does.